# Replace com VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Seguinte, estou fazendo um Filter para buscar algumas palavras passadas por parâmetros e verificar se existe no texto. As palavras que forem iguais terei que destaca-las com um **negrito** e um background. Só que, quando eu coloco a tag strong, o vuejs não renderia adequadamente.

eu tenho algo similiar a isso:

```
<p>{{texto|detarcarPalavra("palavra")}}<p>
```

na saída eu queria que, se a palavra for encontrada, desse um destaque somente nesta palavra.

Comment: Acho que neste caso talvez seja melhor usar o `v-html`. Podes mostrar um exemplo de texto e como queres que o HTML fique?

Comment: O código ta ficando assim: Fundacao <strong>ELE</strong> de Previdencia

Comment: Mas deverá ficar assim: Fundacao **ELE** de Previdencia

Comment: Sim, eu sei. O HTML não é tratado como HTML. Deves usar `<p v-html="detarcarPalavra(texto, "palavra")"><p>`

Comment: Vlw! Deu certo. Pergunta besta, mas eu tinha ficado desnorteado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso seria melhor usar o `v-html`. Esta ferramenta pode abrir buracos de segurança na aplicação, por isso deve ser usada com cuidado.

Mas para o efeito que pretendes podes fazer assim:

```
<p v-html="detarcarPalavra(texto, "palavra")"><p>
```